# How to load image using webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

i want to test if my app can load an image using webdriver.
so when i test it, it does not load the image.
Here is my code:

```
try {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(Component._Image)).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("Choose File Button is displayed");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(Component._Image)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[5]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[5]")).sendKeys("http://website.com/images/image.png");

} catch (NoSuchElementException e)
```

At the end of the test, the image is not loaded.

EDIT: Added html snippet

```
<div class="ctrls"> 
    <input class="image-upload" type="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"></input> 
    <button class="btn image-upload-action"> Choose file </button> 
    <img class="image-preview" style="width: 120px; height: auto; display: none;" alt="Preview"></img> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a HMTL snippet that shows the section of your web page that you're trying to test, thanks.

Comment: The HTML code concerning this part is:     <div class="ctrls">
        <input class="image-upload" type="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"></input>
        <button class="btn image-upload-action">

            Choose file

        </button>
        <img class="image-preview" style="width: 120px; height: auto; display: none;" alt="Preview"></img>
    </div>

</div>

Comment: Well first thing I can notice is that the elements you want to interact with don't seem to be in that HTML. Still, it appears that you're clicking the 'upload' button and then sending the path. Try it the other way around. Send the path to the input element and then click on the submit/upload button.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned,now sometimes it loads the image and sometime not, i do not understand why

Comment: Is this a bug from selenium or is this because the server of the website where we try to load the image is busy sometimes or i don't understand. How can test this part everyday even if i executed several times the same test, it's a wasting time and not enough effecient, do you have a suggestion? Thank you